# Has piperine been shown to be of any use in the treatment of obesity-related diseases in humans?

Tags: natural-remedy, obesity

The 2012 study {1} reports that:

> Taken together, our findings suggest that
>   piperine, a major component of black pepper, inhibits fat cell
>   differentiation by down-regulating the transcriptional activity of
>   PPARγ (and LXRα) and suppressing the expression of PPARγ
>   (and LXRα), thus leading to its potential use in the treatment
>   of obesity-related diseases.

Has piperine been shown to be of any use in the treatment of obesity-related diseases in humans?

---

References:

- {1} Ui-Hyun Park, Hong-Suk Jeong, Eun-Young Jo, Taesun Park, Seung Kew Yoon, Eun-Joo Kim, Ji-Cheon Jeong, Soo-Jong Um. Piperine, a Component of Black Pepper, Inhibits Adipogenesis by Antagonizing PPARγ Activity in 3T3-L1 Cells. Journal of Agricultural and Food Chemistry, 2012; 60 (15): 3853 DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jf204514a

Comment: You might find https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1179/135100004225004742 also interesting - it proves a similar result.

Comment: And it's #2 here: https://www.onlinehomeremedies.com/natural-homemade-remedy-for-obesity/